# In Django, why does the reverse fucntion passes a tuple as argument?

Tags: python, django

The Django tutorial uses the reverse function as `HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))`. The 'results' view is defined as `results(request, question_id)`. I understand that `(question.id,)` is a single element tuple but, why do we even pass a tuple instead of just `question.id`?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial04/

Comment: Some URLs have multiple args, for example you might have `reverse('polls:results', args=(request.user.name, question.id,))` to show all the questions for a particular user. It would be inconsistent if args was a list/tuple sometimes and a single item other times.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you.

Comment: You actually don't have to pass a tuple, you could do something like: 
reverse('polls:results',kwargs={'question_id': question_id})

Comment: It's good to know that. Thank you.